# Fetching data from two tables?

Tags: mysql

I have to find out the output as name of student with highest marks? My both tables are-

```
CREATE TABLE student(Fields_ID INT, Name VARCHAR(20));
        INSERT INTO student(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(30,'JYOTI');
        INSERT INTO student(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(31,'KIRTI');
        INSERT INTO student(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(32,'YOGITA');
        INSERT INTO student(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(33,'RASHMI');
        INSERT INTO student(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(34,'NUPUR');
SELECT * FROM student;
CREATE TABLE Marks(Fields_ID INT, Student_ID INT NOT NULL,marks INT NOT NULL);
        INSERT INTO Marks(Fields_ID,Student_ID,Marks) VALUES (30,40,100);
        INSERT INTO Marks(Fields_ID,Student_ID,Marks) VALUES (31,41,88);
        INSERT INTO Marks(Fields_ID,Student_ID,Marks) VALUES (32,42,72);
        INSERT INTO Marks(Fields_ID,Student_ID,Marks) VALUES (33,43,33);
        INSERT INTO Marks(Fields_ID,Student_ID,Marks) VALUES (34,44,15);
SELECT * FROM Marks;
```

I was trying to return the required out from the following code but it does not return same. Any idea why it is not returning the right values.I am a beginner in MySql so I am unable to find out the problem.

```
   SELECT student.name,Marks.marks
    FROM student INNER JOIN Marks
    ON student.Fields_ID=Marks.Fields_ID;
```

Comment: What does `Student_ID` link to?

Comment: What data is being returned?

Comment: Is that what you need [**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5324/2)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT student.name,Marks.marks
FROM student INNER JOIN Marks
ON student.Fields_ID=Marks.Fields_ID
where Marks.marks = (select max(marks) from Marks);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT student.name,Marks.marks
    FROM student
    INNER JOIN Marks
    ON student.Fields_ID=Marks.Student_ID
ORDER BY Marks.marks DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
       SELECT student.name,Marks.marks
        FROM student INNER JOIN Marks
        ON student.Fields_ID=Marks.Fields_ID
  ORDER by marks DESC;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5324/11

This is desired output?

EDIT: add LIMIT 1 to query if you want JUST ONE result.

Comment: I think you meant 'order by' and not 'Group By'